# 'string' to ['s', 'st', 'str', 'stri', 'strin', 'string']

Tags: ruby

What's the most elegant way of doing

```
'string'
=> ['s', 'st', 'str', 'stri', 'strin', 'string']
```

I've been trying to think of a one liner, but I can't quite get there.
Any solutions are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Abbrev in Standard Library

```
require 'abbrev'
s = Abbrev::abbrev(['string']).keys
puts s.inspect
```

I must add the other way to use this after requiring the Abbrev library, with the .abbrev method added to Array:

```
require 'abbrev'
s = ['string'].abbrev.keys
puts s.inspect
```

If the order is important to match your return in the question, just call `.sort` on `keys`.

Comment: @user21033168, sorry, but interesting as it is to know about this library (personally I didn't know it, thanks @vgoff) I don't see how a solution that requires using `sort` and intermediate objects should be selected instead of any of ther others which do a simple `map`, for example Sergio's.

Comment: @tokland I actually didn't need .sort, so I just liked the shortness of this solution with %w{string}.abbrev.keys :)

Comment: fair enough, though it will be a bit misleading for future SO readers looking for the exact thing what you asked, the "inits" (as Haskell calls it) of a string in Ruby.

Comment: I was unsure if you actually needed sort, or just the member elements needed to be identical.  Sort is only here for ease of human reading of return.

Answer (score 12):

How about this?

```
s = 'string'
res = s.length.times.map {|len| s[0..len]}
res # => ["s", "st", "str", "stri", "strin", "string"]
```

Answer (score 6):

The more declarative I can come up with:

```
s = "string"
1.upto(s.length).map { |len| s[0, len] } 
#=> ["s", "st", "str", "stri", "strin", "string"]
```

Comment: @Sergio. Yeah, I saw, apparently a simple `map` is forbidden to implement this. Whatever.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted either of you, they're fine solutions :)

Comment: @user21033168: I figured, don't worry ;-)

Comment: In fact, this approach (almost) is used by [`abbrev`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/abbrev/rdoc/Abbrev.html#method-c-abbrev) to split the string.

Answer (score 5):

```
s.chars.zip.inject{ |i,j| i << i.last + j.first }
```

Comment: This is actually my favourite solution, because it doesn't refer back to *s* in the method chain and it's clever.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant (this will include the empty string in the result):

```
s.each_char.inject([""]) {|a,ch| a << a[-1] + ch}
```

This

- starts with an array containing the empty string `[""]`
- for each char ch in the string, appends ch to the last result `a[-1] + ch`
- adds this to the result array

Comment: This produces an empty string as first result.

Comment: I get `["", "s", "st", "str", "stri", "strin", "string"]` in Ruby 1.9. A bit convoluted in any case.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "string"
s.each_char.with_object([""]){|i,ar| ar << ar[-1].dup.concat(i)}.drop(1)
#=> ["s", "st", "str", "stri", "strin", "string"]
```